# How can I get the default client certificate of chrome and use it in postman?

Tags: postman, bots, client-certificates

I am using postman to make requests to a certain API however that API uses a bot protection. (Cloudfare)

I noticed that it blocks my requests if I send them from Postman, but it doesn't if I send the exact same request in chrome. The way it blocks is that it detects this with the client certificate.

How can I get the default client certificate what chrome uses and use it inside postman.

Comment: are you sure it uses client certificate ? or it uses useragent property ?

Comment: @PDHide I send the exact same request. That means the same headers, body, etc. So the useragent is the same.